# Extract Original String from rtf tags

Tags: regex, rtf

Regular Expression for extracting original text from  following tags

```
{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid9392958\charrsid9392958 This Sentence is in Calibri with font 11.}
```

Which need to extract  **This Sentence is in Calibri with font 11.**

```
{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \cf17\highlight7\insrsid11236687  with blue font and yello}
```

which need to extract **with blue font and yello**

i write regular expression `\{\\rtlch\\fcs1.*` but it matches full string.
I want regular expression which matches only original text.

Comment: Not sure if regexes are the right approach to this (depends on the complexity/size of your document). Have you checked if the language you are using has no RTF parser?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with this expression :

```
(?:\{\\rtlch\\fcs1 \\\S* \\\S* \\\S*\s*)(.*)(?=\})
```

This expression allow you to capture only the second group, with the first groupe being : `\rtlch\\fcs1 \\\S* \\\S* \\\S*\s*` (i.e. the part you want to avoid).

You can verify it on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aR0zS5/1).

To match expression such as `{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \f39\insrsid9392958 arial black with font 11.\par \ltrrow}` or `{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \i\insrsid9392958\charrsid9392958 This Sentence is in Calibri with font 11.\par }` (as asked in your comment), you can use :

```
(?:\{\\rtlch\\fcs1 \\\S* \\\S* \\\S*\s*)([^\\\}]*)
```

Link to regex101 [for the second expresion](http://regex101.com/r/aR0zS5/2)

NB: you might add a positive lookahead such as `(?=\}|\\)`, but i don't know if you need it.

Comment: thanks for reply.i also want to extract original data from {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \f39\insrsid9392958  arial black with font 11.\par \ltrrow}  


{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \i\insrsid9392958\charrsid9392958 This Sentence is in Calibri with font 11.\par }

Comment: I edited to add an expression that matches all 4 of your strings.